# Vaadin ServletException: Failed to load application class

Tags: java, exception, servlets, vaadin

I have a vaadin and servlet error when i try to load the servlet in the browser by localhost/testVaadin/

I want to execute this sample to see how vaadin works, because I have to implemnt an BPMN with activity explorer, which is using vaadin as a UI framework.

I attached the code, and web.xml plus the thrown exception.

```
package com.example.testvaadin;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Form;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
```

my class

```
public class SimpleAddressBook extends Application {
```

variables

```
private static String[] fields = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Company",
        "Mobile Phone", "Work Phone", "Home Phone", "Work Email",
        "Home Email", "Street", "Zip", "City", "State", "Country" };
private static String[] visibleCols = new String[] { "Last Name",
        "First Name", "Company" };


private Table contactList = new Table();
private Form contactEditor = new Form();
private HorizontalLayout bottomLeftCorner = new HorizontalLayout();
private Button contactRemovalButton;
private IndexedContainer addressBookData = createDummyData();
```

functions

```
@Override
public void init() {
    initLayout();
    initContactAddRemoveButtons();
    initAddressList();
    initFilteringControls();
}

private void initLayout() {
    HorizontalSplitPanel splitPanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
    setMainWindow(new Window("Address Book", splitPanel));
    VerticalLayout left = new VerticalLayout();
    left.setSizeFull();
    left.addComponent(contactList);
    contactList.setSizeFull();
    left.setExpandRatio(contactList, 1);
    splitPanel.addComponent(left);
    splitPanel.addComponent(contactEditor);
    contactEditor.setCaption("Contact details editor");
    contactEditor.setSizeFull();
    contactEditor.getLayout().setMargin(true);
    contactEditor.setImmediate(true);
    bottomLeftCorner.setWidth("100%");
    left.addComponent(bottomLeftCorner);
}

private void initContactAddRemoveButtons() {
    // New item button
    bottomLeftCorner.addComponent(new Button("+",
            new Button.ClickListener() {
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    // Add new contact "John Doe" as the first item
                    Object id = ((IndexedContainer) contactList
                            .getContainerDataSource()).addItemAt(0);
                    contactList.getItem(id).getItemProperty("First Name")
                            .setValue("John");
                    contactList.getItem(id).getItemProperty("Last Name")
                            .setValue("Doe");

                    // Select the newly added item and scroll to the item
                    contactList.setValue(id);
                    contactList.setCurrentPageFirstItemId(id);
                }
            }));

    // Remove item button
    contactRemovalButton = new Button("-", new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            contactList.removeItem(contactList.getValue());
            contactList.select(null);
        }
    });
    contactRemovalButton.setVisible(false);
    bottomLeftCorner.addComponent(contactRemovalButton);
}

private void initAddressList() {
    contactList.setContainerDataSource(addressBookData);
    contactList.setVisibleColumns(visibleCols);
    contactList.setSelectable(true);
    contactList.setImmediate(true);
    contactList.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            Object id = contactList.getValue();
            contactEditor.setItemDataSource(id == null ? null : contactList
                    .getItem(id));
            contactRemovalButton.setVisible(id != null);
        }
    });
}

private void initFilteringControls() {
    for (final String pn : visibleCols) {
        final TextField sf = new TextField();
        bottomLeftCorner.addComponent(sf);
        sf.setWidth("100%");
        sf.setInputPrompt(pn);
        sf.setImmediate(true);
        bottomLeftCorner.setExpandRatio(sf, 1);
        sf.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                addressBookData.removeContainerFilters(pn);
                if (sf.toString().length() > 0 && !pn.equals(sf.toString())) {
                    addressBookData.addContainerFilter(pn, sf.toString(),
                            true, false);
                }
                getMainWindow().showNotification(
                        "" + addressBookData.size() + " matches found");
            }
        });
    }
}

private static IndexedContainer createDummyData() {

    String[] fnames = { "Peter", "Alice", "Joshua", "Mike", "Olivia",
            "Nina", "Alex", "Rita", "Dan", "Umberto", "Henrik", "Rene",
            "Lisa", "Marge" };
    String[] lnames = { "Smith", "Gordon", "Simpson", "Brown", "Clavel",
            "Simons", "Verne", "Scott", "Allison", "Gates", "Rowling",
            "Barks", "Ross", "Schneider", "Tate" };

    IndexedContainer ic = new IndexedContainer();

    for (String p : fields) {
        ic.addContainerProperty(p, String.class, "");
    }

    // Create dummy data by randomly combining first and last names
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Object id = ic.addItem();
        ic.getContainerProperty(id, "First Name").setValue(
                fnames[(int) (fnames.length * Math.random())]);
        ic.getContainerProperty(id, "Last Name").setValue(
                lnames[(int) (lnames.length * Math.random())]);
    }

    return ic;
}

}
```

this is the java part

and the web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>testVaadin</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>
    Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Testvaadin Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.testvaadin.SimpleAddressBook</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Testvaadin Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and i use tomcat as webserver (6.0.32)

So the error is :

> rg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE: Exception lors de l'allocation pour la servlet Testvaadin Application javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.example.testvaadin.SimpleAddressBook at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.init(ApplicationServlet.java:71) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: Make it easier for people to help you:
Formulate your actual question in short words and put it before the source code. 
We need details about what you want to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Much better that way :-) Thanks for improving it.

Comment: thank you very much karin . most of people here close the question without make a remarque. you are an angel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the error message is saying `com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet` tried to load `com.example.testvaadin.SimpleAddressBook` during initialisation and didn't succeed.

To resolve this try the following:

- check if the application deployment succeeded and the class: `SimpleAddressBook` is really in the right place in your servlet container
- check if there is a `vaadin-xx.yy.zz.jar` in WEB-INF/lib
- clean and rebuild the entire project

Comment: @Anis Bouchenafa: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951077/vaadin-generated-page-doesnt-show-any-component) mean you solved the problem? If yes it would be great if you could write a short comment here for future visitors. It will help them to know what did the trick in your case.

Comment: yes ,it works .the problems was : when i exported the application to the war extenssion, eclipse did not generate the classes.[br] and i installed a new version of vaadin 7.0 .