# Spring configuration problems - Failed to load application class

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, vaadin, web.xml

well I am trying to add Spring dependency injection to my project, ever since I added all the required stuff for spring integration into my project, the web project fails to deploy... 
Why do I think it has something to do with my Spring configuration? Well BEFORE adding any spring configuration the Vaadin gui, the servlet DEPLOYED perfectly and so did the jersey rest web service...

Now I'm getting this error when trying to run it:

```
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-01-13 20:46:27,984 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2013-01-13 20:46:28,140 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Jan 13 20:46:28 EET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-01-13 20:46:28,247 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/nortal/pirs/spring/application-context.xml]
2013-01-13 20:46:28,750 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@275d728c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-01-13 20:46:28,850 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 861 ms
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:28 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.nortal.pirs.webservices
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.15 10/30/2012 03:41 PM'
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /PIRS_Fix threw load() exception
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7132 ms
Sau 13, 2013 8:46:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet PirsVaadinFrontend
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.nortal.pirs.presentation.vaadin.PirsVaadinController
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.init(ApplicationServlet.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried removing the jersey web service servlet part, but it still couldn't load the vaadin frontend servlet, if you need the error without jersey, I could post it, but I thought it wouldn't be necessary.

My web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>PIRS_Web</display-name>

    <!-- Vaadin -->

    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PirsVaadinFrontend</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.nortal.pirs.presentation.vaadin.PirsVaadinController
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PirsVaadinFrontend</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com\nortal\pirs\spring\application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- EmailCheck REST web service -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>emailCheckService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.nortal.pirs.webservices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>emailCheckService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- General parameters -->
    <!-- <session-config> <session-timeout>240</session-timeout> </session-config> -->

</web-app>
```

My Spring application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support -->
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nortal.pirs.test.independent"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nortal.pirs.businesslogic.logic"></context:component-scan>

    <!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

If I remove the Jersey part, I get this:

```
 2013-01-13 20:35:23,630 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 741 ms
Sau 13, 2013 8:35:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sau 13, 2013 8:35:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sau 13, 2013 8:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6144 ms
Sau 13, 2013 8:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet PirsVaadinFrontend
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.nortal.pirs.presentation.vaadin.PirsVaadinController
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.init(ApplicationServlet.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The webservice class looks like this:

```
    package com.nortal.pirs.webservices;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.nortal.pirs.businesslogic.factories.ControllerFactoryProvider;
import com.nortal.pirs.businesslogic.interfaces.UserManagerInterface;

@Path("/emailcheck/{emailAddress}")
public class EmailCheckService {

    //@Autowired
    //@Qualifier("UserManager")
    private UserManagerInterface userManager = ControllerFactoryProvider.getInstance().createUserManager();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String emailExists(@PathParam("emailAddress") String email) {
        if (userManager.emailExists(email)) {
            return "true";
        } else {
            return "false";
    }
    }

    public void setUserManager(UserManagerInterface userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

Anyone came accross this kind of problem? I thought it was because I added spring to the configuration, however it seems it doesn't work even if I remove it, indeed nothing from the web.xml seems to work now... Maybe it's something with Tomcat? I'm using Tomcat 7, configured in Eclipse. I tried cleaning it, but it doesn't seem to help as well. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey couldn't find any class which can be executed as Jersey RESTful web service.

Check:

- Whether `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` is missing in your `web.xml` - seems ok.
- Whether value for `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` param is missing or invalid - I cannot tell.
- Whether there is at least one POJO which has a method annotated with `@Path` - I cannot tell.
- If the [many Google hits](https://www.google.ch/search?q=com.sun.jersey.api.container.containerexception%3a%20The%20ResourceConfig%20instance%20does%20not%20contain%20any%20root%20resource%20classes.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for this exception help you any further.

Comment: Well I edited and supplied the webservice file, however even without the webservice part in web.xml it still fails to deploy. And it's not spring, cause to be honest, none of what is in web.xml seems to work now...

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if your `Resource` classes are located in this package ( `com.nortal.pirs.webservices` ) as defined in your web.xml? Your server log indicates the resource classes cannot be found. Assuming if that package contains the `Resource` classes, the server log will show a list of the classes. I have a project that uses both Spring and Jersey together without problem.

Perhaps, you might want to disable `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` for `PirsVaadinFrontend` in your web.xml and debug the Jersey error first. You have 2 different errors here, and I can't be sure if it is one problem that causes the other problem or if you have 2 independent problems.

Comment: Well I edited my question with the code of that file, as you can see it's in that package. The thing is, it did work and I didn't change the package structure. However for one thing I was wrong. It can't be Spring, because I've removed it an still it's all the same, so what previously worked, now doesn't work at all. 
It also says: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.nortal.pirs.presentation.vaadin.PirsVaadinController The one I have in my question. I'm suspecting it's one problem mainly, well the one who's blocking the servlet from getting deployed

Comment: Do both of these links solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929352/vaadin-servletexception-failed-to-load-application-class and https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1633987